# Identifying SMD motherboard component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

My motherboard (Gigabyte b450) died after a power outage. I found out that an SMD 5-pin IC with the code ***VA8qE*** was burned. I tried to identify it myself, with no luck.

I searched for the code online, but no result, even on pages like:

- https://alltransistors.com/smd-search.php
- https://smd.yooneed.one/

Any idea what it is?

[image]

Comment: Not found as a Code or PN  . Is there another number? or brand symbol  https://www.sphere.bc.ca/download/smd-codebook.pdf

Comment: A detailed photo of the motherboard and the burnt part might help get you an answer.

Comment: UPDATE: with actual picture of the component, seem that 5 pic give voltage to the ITE chip. there is a exact chip near the chipset, i removed that one and replaced the burned, now the mobo turn on, but no video, so i sill need to replace it.

Comment: Could it be one of the "VAB" components listed at https://smd.yooneed.one/code5641.html ? Does the working one have an output of 1.1 V?

Answer (score 2):

I think it says "VAB", in which case it's probably a [S-1135 Series voltage regulator](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/voltage_regulator/S1135_E.pdf).

More specifically the "S-1135C11-M5T1y", according to the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some reading with the multimer on the same 5 pin not burned VA8qE next to the chipset, it looks like it a voltage regulator, 5 V input 3.3 V output. I found (different code) in an old motherboard I had around, measure, and the MOBO is live again, booted to BIOS so far.